unity cloud project showing blank project instead of actual project (unity version control)
My friend invited me to join his unity project but when I load it I get a blank project with all the scripts and assets of my friend. It's like the scene doesnt load for some reasons

The scenes in Unity don't always load automatically.You can find the needed scene in the assets folder and double-click to load it.
